# I want good reference books or video links that may help me in learning Webobjects using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, webobjects

Can any one post some links that help me in learning WebObjects with eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitively THE source for al WebObjects and Eclipse/Wolips :
http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/dashboard.action

You can also suscribe to the webobjects-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following 2 links for a great source of information:

- http://www.wocommunity.org/page/default
  (Intro and video tutorials etc)
- http://wiki.objectstyle.org/confluence/dashboard.action
  (Wiki for everything)

Also as a good if slightly dated basic WebObjects reference Chucks Hill's "Practical WebObjects" is a good primer on some core webobjects concepts.

- Some podcasts available here as well
  http://www.wocommunity.org/podcasts/wopodcasts.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you have a copy of Ravi Mendis book or the Wrox book, you can get a copy of the examples as Eclipse/WOLips project here :

https://services.wocommunity.org/books/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone find this thread: a new book have been published, and it's the only printed books with references to WOLips and Project Wonder. The book is "Learning the Wonders", http://www.learningthewonders.com/